# Как пробежаться по всем открытым вкладкам браузера?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Необходимо пробежаться по всем вкладкам браузера в поисках одной переменной. Как это сделать?

Comment: То есть, подсмотреть содержимое других вкладок? Нарушить безопастность?

Comment: Ответ: мышкой.

Comment: зачем мышкой, мне программно надо.
может и нарушить безопасность, но мне просто надо посмотреть на каких вкладках открыт мой сайт, и играет плеер, чтобы его(плеер) выключить, как это реализовано вконтакте

Comment: Пишите переменную в cookies.

Comment: ВК это реализовано с помощью comet, как я понял.

Comment: @Sh4dow чушь не городите.

Comment: @lampa я могу ошибаться, ведь я всего лишь человек) (с) Просто замечал, что у них постоянно висит notifer.js и подумал, что раз уж я все им обновляю, впилил бы туда и плеер тоже.

Comment: @Sh4dow ну теперь, я надеюсь, вы будете более досконально изучать, как работают системы :-)

Answer (score 1):

В вк это реализовано через localstorage. Что за извращение "чтобы узнать где играет плеер пробежаться по всем вкладкам". При включении вашего плеера - сохраняйте значение "вкл.". При записи в localstorage переменную значения "выкл." - выключайте плеер.